# Getting Relative Paths

Tags: php

Super noob question here...

The file source:
www.mysite.com/blah/blah/customdir/ajax/folder/file.php

and I want to include a source:

www.mysite.com/blah/blah/customdir/include/func/functions.php

So I have tried:

```
require_once( '.../include/func/functions.php' );
require_once( '../include/func/functions.php' );
require_once( '././include/func/functions.php' );
```

and a ton of other variations.  How do I get to it?  Setting a top level path on every file isn't an option (that's what the function file is for...)

Each of the above is giving me an error:
Warning: include(././include/func/functions.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/mysite.com/customdir/ajax/folder/index.php on line 3

Warning: include(././include/func/functions.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/mysite.com/customdir/ajax/folder/index.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '././include/func/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/public_html/mysite.com/customdir/ajax/folder/index.php on line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to include a file. However, it seems you are attempting relative paths. In which case, try:

```
require_once '../../include/func/functions.php';
```

I encourage you to [learn more about your options for including files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). But in a nutshell, each `../` takes you back a directory. `./` represents the current directory. Otherwise, you can always use an absolute path or even (gulp) a hybrid.

Comment: It works.  Thanks.  Why does it take double periods?  Lame... tried so many things.

Comment: Cause it's two directories above the current script. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running under apache?  use getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") and set your path from there.